# Converting XY coordinate points to Lat Lon

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude

I have a set of points representing the nodes making up a polygon from a city-border. These points are projected in RD New EPSG:28992 (The Netherlands). I want to convert these coordinates to Lat Lon.
I have tried to save the layer as a new layer with the WGS:84 EPSG:4326 projection and opened this new layer in a new project with the same CRS.
However, this either shows a completely warped view of the points in a wrong place or it simply shows nothing.

[image: The original shape in RD NEW]
Original shape in RD New
[image]
Warped points in Lat Lon/WGS:84

Am I missing something obvious here? I am not new to QGIS and have done this trick with other CRS's lots of other times.

Comment: looks right to me, lat lon is often a quite different shape that when projected

Comment: Yes, you are right. Quite obvious.

Comment: You can always change your *project projection* (bottom right button) to RD-whatever and use On-the-fly reprojection to make your lat-long epsg:4326 data look like the RD-thingy projection map.

Answer (score 5):

Your reprojection is fine. The problem with lat lon is that how higher or lower you get from the equator the more the map reforms. This is due to the fact that the earth is a sphere and not flat.

You can solve this problem for example with a map curator: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator